# getParseFile(string key) returning null from Parse.com with extended ParseObject class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

I have an extended ParseObject class with 6 fields. All of the fields return the correct data except for the ParseFile getter method. Getting ParseFiles the old fashioned way works but for some reason when I use an extended class, the data is null when GetDataCallback is called. It has an URL and image name but the data field is null.

My extended class:

```
package [mypackage];

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ParseClassName("Listing")
public class Listing extends ParseObject implements Serializable {
    private boolean  active;
    private String description, title, username;
    private int price;
    private ParseFile file;

    public Listing() {
        super();
    }

    public void setDetail(boolean active, String description, String title,
                          String username, int price, ParseFile file) {
        this.active = active;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
        this.username = username;
        this.file = file;
    }

    /* getter methods */
    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return getBoolean("active");
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return getString("description");
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return getInt("price");
    }

    public String getListingTitle() { /* getTitle() reserved by android */
        return getString("title");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return getString("username");
    }

    public ParseFile getFile() {
        return getParseFile("image");
    }
}
```

Where the getter methods are called:

```
public void getListings() {
        ParseQuery<Listing> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Listing.class);
        /* only retrieve active listings */
        query.whereEqualTo("active", true);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Listing>() {

            @Override
            //public void done(List<ParseObject> listingList, ParseException e) {
            public void done(List<Listing> listingList, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("listing", "Retrieved " + listingList.size() + " listings");
                    /* clear adapter before populating */
                    adapter.clear();
                    /* iterate through listings and create listing objects */
                    for (Listing listingObject : listingList) {
                        boolean active;
                        String description, title, username;
                        int price;

                        active = listingObject.getIsActive();
                        username = listingObject.getUsername();
                        description = listingObject.getDescription();
                        title = listingObject.getListingTitle();
                        price = listingObject.getPrice();
                        file =  listingObject.getFile();

                        /* create a listing object to be added to a ListView */    
                        Listing listing = new Listing();
                        listing.setDetail(active, description, title, username, price, file);
                        listings.add(listing);

                    } /* end for loop */
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("listing", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listing_row_item, null);
        }

        Listing listing = listings.get(position);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listing_title);
        TextView priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listing_price);
        final ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPicture);

        titleView.setText(listing.getListingTitle());
        priceView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(listing.getPrice()));

        listing.getFile().getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() { //getFile() returns null

            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
```

**EDIT:**
I believe my fundamental misunderstanding was how to set the values of the extended ParseObject. As the answer below shows, the `put` Parse methods here actually put the values in the object. I was under the impression that `put` was only ever for actual database operations and my setter method was therefore not setting up the ParseObject correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uggh... We were so close. I found the problem, you werent setting the values to the fields in your ParseObject, which is why everything was null in the adapter. Add the following to your Listing class and change the setDetail method as follows:

```
public void setDetail(boolean active, String description, String title,
                      String username, int price, ParseFile file) {

    setIsActive(active);
    setIsActive(description);
    setPrice(price);
    setListingTitle(title);
    setUsername(username);
    setFile(file);
}

public void setIsActive(boolean a) {
    put("active", a);
}

public void setDescription(String s) {
    put("description", s);
}

public void setPrice(int p) {
    put("price", p);
}

public void setListingTitle(String t) {
    put("title", t);
}

public void setUsername(String u) {
    put("username", u);
}

public void setFile(ParseFile f) {
    put("image", f);
}
```

**Old Answer**

I maybe wrong but I'm pretty sure that you're supposed to save the URL of the ParseFile and not the ParseFile itself and use the URL to fetch the file. So in the done (..) method you should do something like:

```
file.getUrl();
```

And set it as a String. Moving on, if

Comment: Your method might work but this is not how I want to do it. I am doing it just like they do in their Mealspotting app tutorial.

Comment: Do note that the tutorials haven't been updated in a while, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Well for now I'm going to go back to not using the my object for retrieving data. That still works fine. It's frustrating that all database operations work except for ParseFile. It kinda defeats the purpose of having your own class if you can't use it.

Comment: It's weird, as far as I can tell, the file part of the object looks exactly the same when doing it the old way so I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: I may have caught something. When you're adding the values and stuff in setDetail() you're not using them anywhere. To test this, add another method in your subclass which returns the "file" and in your adapter use that method as well to get the file.

Comment: I see what you're saying but doesn't the setDetail modify the listingObject to add the details? So I should be "using" them in the ListingAdapter, no? The data from the object shows in the debugger but it does not appear to be making it to the ListingAdapter.

Comment: I haven't used a ParseObject this way so I can't say.. But by looking at the code, thats what I think. Comment out the file part from the adapter and check if the other data is retrieved.

Comment: Success! For some reason, the details of my extended ParseObject would not pass to the adapter even though they were showing in the debugger. I ended up passing the object blank and getting the details in the adapter. Updating my question now. Could you add something to your answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Lol it worked? I just found the problem. Answer updated

Comment: I see, so the "put" is actually just putting it into the object, not into the database? This was my fundamental misunderstanding, I think.

Comment: Yeah, it was just adding the value to the specifed field in the local object.